# Apache2 python script works when run in command line but not when run in web browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, apache2, boto3

My python script uses boto3 and I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'` when running my python script in the browser. I am running apache2 on my ec2 instance with ubuntu.

- I have the latest version of pip installed.
- My python version is Python 3.10.4.
- I have the latest version of boto3 and botocore installed.

My python code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n")
print("<H1> Hello, From python server :) </H1>")
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import math
import boto3 #Error occurs here
```

My apache2.conf file is as follows:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/my-website/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>
```

I have spent 10 hours trying to figure the issue out. I tried reinstalling boto3 and using the `sys` module to directly import the path but that did not work. Any help is appreciated as I am completely stumped. Thanks

Comment: You already asked that. What's different in this question then before?

Comment: I didn't think I gave enough info before. Was hoping someone would be able to help as I did not receive a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't install boto3 with root priveleges, then it's only available for the user that installed it. Running `sudo pip install boto3` fixed it for me, as it will install it for ALL users, however it is better to use a virtual environment as running pip as `root` can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour.